# PostgreSQL field type for unix timestamp?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

PostgreSQL field type for unix timestamp :

- to store it as unix time stamp
- to retrieve it as a unix timestamp as well.

Have been going through [Date/Time Types <sup>postgreSQL V 9.1</sup>](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html).

---

- Is integer the best way to go!? (this is what I had done when I was using MySQL. Had used `int(10)`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

integer would be good, but not enough good, because postgresql doesn't support unsigned types

Comment: I think I can counter that with a check to make it behave like an unsigned number.

Comment: until 2038 this is not a problem :)

Comment: probably use bigint then. But it would not be good to store the extra bits.

Comment: Maia storage really so expensive that you need to worry about a couple of bytes extra per row?

Comment: @GordonM Sorry to grave dig, but highly depends on the traffic your database receives..

Answer (score 141):

The unix epoch timestamp right now (2014-04-09) is 1397071518. So we need an data type capable of storing a number at least this large.

**What data types are available?**

If you refer to the PostgreSQL [documentation on numeric types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html) you'll find the following options:

```
Name      Size     Minimum               Maximum
smallint  2 bytes  -32768                +32767
integer   4 bytes  -2147483648           +2147483647
bigint    8 bytes  -9223372036854775808  +9223372036854775807
```

**What does that mean in terms of time representation?**

Now, we can take those numbers and convert them into dates using an [epoch converter](http://www.epochconverter.com/):

```
Name      Size     Minimum Date      Maximum Date
smallint  2 bytes  1969-12-31        1970-01-01
integer   4 bytes  1901-12-13        2038-01-18
bigint    8 bytes  -292275055-05-16  292278994-08-17
```

Note that in the last instance, using seconds puts you so far into the past and the future that it probably doesn't matter. The result I've given is for if you represent the unix epoch in milliseconds.

**So, what have we learned?**

1. `smallint` is clearly a bad choice.
2. `integer` is a decent choice for the moment, but your software will blow up in the year 2038. The Y2K apocalypse has nothing on the [Year 2038 Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).
3. **Using `bigint` is the best choice.** This is future-proofed against most conceivable human needs, though [the Doctor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_%28Doctor_Who%29) may still [criticise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utopia_%28Doctor_Who%29) it.

You may or may not consider whether it might not be best to store your timestamp in another format such as the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

Comment: very good answer and very well ilustrated the pro and cons of each data type

Answer (score 35):

I'd just go with using TIMESTAMP WITH(OUT) TIME ZONE and use EXTRACT to get a UNIX timestamp representation when you need one.

Compare

```
SELECT NOW();
```

with

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM NOW());
```

Comment: As I am saying, I want to store Unix timestamps. Does the timestamp datatype store the literal `unix timestamp`?

Comment: `TIMESTAMP WITH(OUT) TIME ZONE` does not store the literal timestamps.

Comment: I really don't think the downvote was called for.  Postgres doesn't have a data type that literally maps to unix timestamp. You have to either use postgres timestamp or a non-temporal type. If you do the latter you won't be able to use SQL to compare timestamps

Comment: I down voted because I have clearly mentioned in the question as to store/retrieve unix timestamp. Not because Postgres doesn't have a data type that literally maps to unix timestap. PEACE.

Comment: Then convert to Postgres timestamp on store and convert back (with extract like I showed you) when you fetch the data back. It's a better solution than bodging it with an int or string

Comment: By default `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` is stored as a 64-bit integer of the microseconds from midnight 2000-01-01 UTC (ignoring leap seconds, so really more like UT1). That converts pretty quickly and easily to Unix time, while allowing easy presentation and date math. If you really want the coarser resolution, integer presentation, and difficulty in date calculations, feel free to use bigint or numeric. There aren't too many situations where that's a net win, but maybe you have one of those few.